# Using mechanize to click a button with onclick="return somejsfunction()"

Tags: javascript, python, mechanize

Here's the javascript for the button I'd like to click using mechanize:

```
<form id="fLogin" method="post">
<input type="button" id="qLogin" name="qLogin" value="Login" onclick="return submitfunction();" class="qloginb" />
```

it's not recognize as clickable by mechanize. Here is the code for "submitfunction()":

```
function submitfunction()
{       

    var form = document.getElementById("fLogin");


    form.action = "/someurl/etc" + "&val1=" + val1.value + "&id1=" + id.Value;


    form.submit();
 }
```

Is there a way to 'simulate' clicking this button? From what I've read, it looks like doing something like this might work: "br.form.action="the wanted action" but I'm not sure how exactly to implement this approach. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to be logged in without using mechanize by constructing a URL from the form.action line and passing the login credentials in the query string:

http://www.example.com/someurl/etc?val1=somevalue&id1=someid&password=examplepassword&username=exampleusername